# How Can I do c# dictionary for php but. Loop class

Tags: c#, php, class, dictionary, for-loop

I want to convert this C# code to PHP code.

```
class Members
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}

class Process
{

    Dictionary<string, Members> MemberList = new Dictionary<string, Members>();
    public Process()
    {

        //GetMembersMethod();
        //Fill MemberList
        //example
        //MemberList.Add(userid,new Members{id=@id,name=@name,surname=@surname});
    }

    void WriteMembers() {
        foreach (string item in MemberList.Keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(MemberList[item].ID);
            Console.WriteLine(MemberList[item].Name);
            Console.WriteLine(MemberList[item].Surname);
        }
    }
}
```

### How I can code this c# example in PHP? How can I code the loop to dictionary using array classes with PHP?

### Edit..

I coded 2 days ago this code;
I want to like to this..

```
<?php
class CKN
    {
        public $Name= 'ozan';
        public $Surname= 'ckn';
        public $ID = '12';
    }
    $class = new CKN();
    for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
        $class_temp= new CKN();
        $class_temp->Name="ozan".$i;
        $class_temp->Surname="CKN".$i;  
        $class_temp->ID="CKN".$i;
        $arr[$i]=(object)$class_temp;
    }
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        $temp=new (CKN)$value;
        foreach($temp as $k=>$v){
            print "$k=> $v <br>";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is a fairly basic stuff, you just need to understand that php isn't strongly-typed language and adapt to that.

Comment: What....? C#? PHP? those are different things.

Comment: gdoron c# code to php code.
How to write c# example code in php :(

--
walther.
Already trying to figure out
But I dont create this c# methods like php method..

I am coding a longest time with php but never used this way..

Comment: The answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597996/searching-for-php-equivalent-for-javas-map-and-list) also answers your own question.

Comment: Shadow Wizard thanks but not answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using http://jsc.sourceforge.net/, which assists with .net to javascript, actionscript or php.

If you want to do it yourself:

1. Classes are declared in pretty much the same way
2. Dictionaries are loosely reducible to hashmaps, which can be substituted by php "arrays"
3. Replace the console with your desired output stream.
4. Remove typed declarations. All variables start with $.

I might have missed something, but that should get you started. Good luck.

EDIT: Here is code that I think does what you need. You can test it [here](http://www.phpfiddle.org/main/code/ykx-uv1):

```
<?php
class CKN
{
    public $Name= 'ozan';
    public $Surname= 'ckn';
    public $ID = '12';
}
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
    $class_temp= new CKN();
    $class_temp->Name="ozan".$i;
    $class_temp->Surname="CKN".$i;  
    $class_temp->ID="CKN".$i;
    $arr[$i]=$class_temp;
}
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    foreach($value as $k=>$v){
        print "$k=> $v <br>";
    }
}
?>
```